# when installing Bigcommerce stencil as detailed below. how to troubleshoot and fix the issue

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

Installing Bigcommerce Stencil CLI

**>> npm install -g bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli**

When I try the above code in cmd, it throws an error Please find the below error screen
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a permissions issue/publickey.

This should provide some guidance to resolve: [Error: Permission Denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/#platform-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I received this issue when I did not have my work github ssh key set up on my home computer. I believe this shouldn't be an issue anymore once stencil is 100% launched, but as long as it is private, you need your github ssh keys to identify yourself to clone the repo.